# Count number of tabs within tabset generated by ng-repeat with Selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, selenium, junit

I'm testing a webpage which has a number of tabs within a `tabset` generated with `ng-repeat`.

My tabs are generated as follows:

```
<tabset id="tabset">
    <tab ng-repeat="server in servers">
        <tab-heading>{{server.name}}</tab-heading>
        <div>{{server.body}}</div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

My attempt at testing is:

```
@Test
public void shouldDisplayAtLeastOneServer() {
    Assert.assertThat(webDriver.findElement(By.id("tabset"))
            .findElements(By.tagName("tab"))
            .size(), Matchers.greaterThan(0));
}
```

But is failing as size is 0 while I know 4 tabs are visible.

Comment: Are the tabs inside `<frame>` or `<iframe>` tag?

Comment: i see you have one tab so the size need to be one (index[0])

Comment: Hi Guy, the tabs are inside a `<div>`, I'm hoping I've got the right end of the stick there. Leon Barkan, the use of `ng-repeat` means there will be multiple tabs, I know this as I can see them on the webpage when I load it myself.

Comment: The `<frame>` doesn't have to be immediate parent, it can be an ancestor.

Comment: Presumably the element isn't within a frame as a NoSuchElementException isn't thrown when finding the `tabset` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, Angular has had its way with the code structure!

Its been transformed:

`<tabset id="tabset">` into `<div id="tabset" ...>` and `<ul class="nav nav-tab" ...>`

`<tab>` into `<li ...>`

Therefore, the following has succeeded:

```
@Test
public void shouldDisplayAtLeastOneServer() {
Assert.assertThat(webDriver.findElement(By.id("tabset"))
        .findElement(By.tagName("ul"))
        .findElements(By.tagName("li"))
        .size(), Matchers.greaterThan(0));
}
```

Comment: Glad you found your own answer. Please don't forget to come back and accept this answer when you can. Thanks!

Comment: Will do, I can accept it tomorrow. Hopefully this will helps others avoid getting into a pickle as I did